# Icons showing on iPhone 5s but not on iPhone 6

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

I have a twitter and facebook button on my site.

HTML :

```
<button id="o-share_btn_facebook" class="o-share_btn_facebook">Post</button>
<button id="o-share_btn_twitter" class="o-share_btn_twitter">Tweet</button>
```

then they both have a background image for to display the twitter and facebook icons :

```
background-image: url(https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/spathtoimages/whiteshareicont.svg);
```

The icons show on all browsers and iPhone 5s and everything. However not on the iPhone 6.

I disabled ad blocker on a friends iPhone 6 and it then displayed the icons. I'm just wondering is there anyway around showing them? Other images show but just not them which is weird.

I've tried researching a lot but it's a weird issue and struggling.

Comment: There's not much to go on here but it sounds as if the Content Blocker your friend has installed (they can block more than just ad's) is blocking the share buttons for Facebook and Twitter. This is common as of iOS 9 and you cannot rely on your users not having a Content Blocker installed.

Comment: Try different `id` and `class` names, usually Ad Blockers block anything that has the words `ad` or `share` and similar related terms. (not 100% sure tho, test it)